# How to save many pages configuration of a terminal?

Tags: command-line

When I open the terminal, it can open  four pages,such as src, CMakeList.txt, rosmake fuctions.

[image]

How to save all pages directory when I need it ,I can load all pages in new terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using [Terminator](https://launchpad.net/terminator/)?

Terminator, multiple terminals in one window.

The goal of this project is to produce a useful tool for arranging terminals.
It is inspired by programs such as gnome-multi-term, quadkonsole, etc. in that
the main focus is arranging terminals in grids (tabs is the most common default
method, which Terminator also supports).

Answer (score 1):

See if you like this. To open many pages in VI, create a script to open them with one command or do it maunally -->

```
vi -p /home/user/first.txt /home/user/second.txt <-- Open these two files.
vi -p /home/user/*.txt  <-- Open all of the txt files in that folder.
```

Then to switch tabs -->

```
gt            go to next tab
gT            go to previous tab
```

Here is some more info -->
[VIM tab control](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_tab_pages)